Election notifications aren't being sent
I only discovered the election because I happened to check meta, which I don't do every day here. (The sidebar? It's carefully designed to be discrete and boring, so whoever notices anything there?)
I only just realized that I should have received an inbox notification, but didn't. (I checked my inbox, nope, I didn't miss it, it's not there). Given the extremely low (17) number of visitors to the election page (for comparison, there were 46 on Network Engineering, which also held an election while still having the beta design), I guess I'm not the only one. And I haven't received a notification of the election phase, either.
Election notifications are not being sent. I can't think of a good reason not to do it, and I can't find anything about that on MSE, so I'm chalking it out as a bug.
I'm told that Chemistry and Biology users weren't notified either.
Sending notifications now wouldn't significantly affect voting on Crypto.SE, but it's too late for anyone to nominate. Should the nomination period be extended?

I just got a "please vote in the election" notification. As for extension - if there is someone who wants to self-nominate (speak now?), I think it should be extended. If not, then there's no need.

@Reid So did I. Seems the notification sender goblins' strike has just been busted.

Well, that's not good... I pushed the notifications through. Jarrod just pushed a fix for the bug, so we should be back to business as usual starting with the next build.
However, I'm afraid there's no way to extend the nomination at this stage short of scrapping the whole election and starting over.

As the last candidate to join the election, just six hours before the end of the nomination phase, I'd say that if any established user comes forward and says they meant to nominate themselves but missed the deadline, we should restart the election. I'd certainly be quite disappointed if I'd happened to visit the site a few hours later, and missed the chance to nominate myself.
